# Modeling data in Redis

Tags: memory-management, redis

I am building a system that keeps track of many counters in real time in Redis. Each counter is basically the impression, conversion details for ad keywords shown on a specific url.

ie. if 10 keywords are shown on a specific url, I need to update a count for each of those keywords for both impressions and conversions. And on each impression of a url, possibly a different set of 10 keywords can be shown.

ie. the basic data model I need is something like

- > url=>

> ```
>  k1 =>
>         impression => 2
>         conversion => 1
>  k2 =><br>
>         impression => 100
>         conversion => 8
>  .
>  .
>  k100 (max around 100)</li>
> ```
>
> I understand Redis doesnt have nested hashes so I cant store a 2 level hash as I have shown above.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I thought of combining k1-impression and k1 conversion and making it one single field

ie like

- url =>

> ```
>    k1-impression => 100
>    k1-conversion => 3
>    .<br>
>    . so on</li>
> ```
>
> But the problem is the lengths of 'k1', 'k2' etc is significant ( 120-150 bytes) and I dont want to replicate that data, if possible, to save on memory.

How would I go about solving this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keywords are of significant enough length that you're worried about it, you should normalize them.  Make a hash of `keyword -> id`, and a hash of `id -> keyword`, for encoding and decoding them.  Then you can have per-url hashes of the form `url => {kw_id:impressions => 1123, kw_id:conversions => 28}`.  This will also serve you well when you start needing to make indexes of the key words, which you will as soon as you get a requirement to show the top 10 best performing key words across all urls, for example.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But is this the best way to model my data? Can I use any of the other (Sets,Lists etc) to do it more efficiently? I am just starting with Redis and any help will be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Best for what case? The only concern you mentioned in the question was not replicating the key word text, which is what I designed for.  Depending on specifically what you are trying to do, all the redis data types are useful, you just need to chose the right tool for the job.  Every redis command lists its complexity class in the documentation.  Think about your query patterns, and look at the complexity of the redis commands you will need to implement those queries. Then just chose the structures that minimize your complexity.